# function assistance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I think I only need a little help with this, I think I undertsand it.

[image]

What I have got so far is:

$12.8 = -log_{10} (H^+)$

Multiply both sides by a negative 1 (bad thing to do?)

$10^{-12.8} = H^+$

$H^+ = 1.584893192*10^{-13}$

I'm not sure what "(Write your answer using scientific notation. Round the mantissa (the coefficient of 10) to the nearest hundredth.)" means, and also not sure if my manipluation with the negate sign is correct.

Edit: I know what scientific notation is i.e. $1.3$ x $10^{11}$ I don't know what the mantissa is, or how to round it.

EDIT#2: I also realize my answer is wrong as it is a negative number.

Comment: The mantissa is the part of a floating point number consisting of its significant digits.  In this case: 1.584893192.  So you want to round this to three significant figures.  Thus $1.58\,\mathrm{E}{-}13$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.  Multiplying by ${-1}$ is *exactly* what you are supposed to do, followed by taking the antilog.

$\mathrm{pH} = 12.8 $ $\implies -\log_{10}([\mathrm{H}^+]) = 12.8 \\ \implies \log_{10}([\mathrm{H}^+])= - 12.8 \\ \implies \log_{10}([\mathrm{H}^+])=0.2-13 \\ \implies [\mathrm{H}^+]= 10^{0.2}\times 10^{-13} \\ \implies [\mathrm{H}^+]= 1.584893192\ldots\times 10^{-13}$

The "mantissa" is the part of a floating point number consisting of its significant digits. Also, the "exponent" is the integer indicating of the power of ten by which you multiply the mantissa.

Scientific notation consists of writing the mantissa followed multiplication by ten raised to the exponent.  It may also be expressed as the mantissa followed by the letter 'E' and then the exponent (with its signage indicated).

In this case the mantissa is: "$1.584893192$". So you want to round this to three significant figures.

Thusly: $1.58{\times}10^{-13}$ or $1.58\;\mathrm{E}{−}13$

Comment: So I had it right, I just needed to round it? thank you!